# How to upgrade codeigniter from very old version to latest one

Tags: codeigniter

My site is developed in codeigniter 1.7.2. Unfortunately I could not upgrade it earlier. Now I want to upgrade my site from 1.7.2 to 2.1.3. I have found links to upgrade from codeignter 1.7.2 to 2.0 and then 2.0 to 2.0.1 etc. I am confused either I can upgrade directly from 1.7.2 to 2.1.3 or there are limitation in doing that. Thanks for any help.

Regards...

Comment: Have you read this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrade_200.html And this, http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/209890/#976726

Comment: Please add the actual answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.7.x to 2.0.x is the jump where you need to follow the upgrade steps;  2.0 on up, simply replace your system dir with the newer one